# Proof of inverse of composite functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $A$, $B$ & $C$ sets, and left $f:A \rightarrow B$  and $g:B \rightarrow C$ be functions. Suppose that $f$ and $g$ have inverses.  Prove that $g\circ f$ has an inverse, and that $(g\circ f)^{−1} = f^{−1}\circ g^{−1}$.

Assuming that f and g have reverse,$f^{-1}=h$ and $g^{-1}=s$ with $h:B\rightarrow A$  e $s:C\rightarrow B$.

from that above i infer that the inverse of $(g \circ f)$ is 
      $(s \circ g):C\rightarrow A$ that is $g^{-1} \circ f^{-1}=(g \circ         f)^{-1}$;
 Hence for proof of $(g \circ f)^{-1}=f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}$, proceed as before, only swapping functions , right?

Comment: Please: clarify your question. There are some evident mistakes in your proof, contradicting each other.

Comment: Please where are the errors?

Comment: You have to prove that the inverse of $g \circ f$ is $h \circ s$, while you say that the inverse is $s \circ g$. But obviously you have $s \circ g = id_B$ by definition of $s = g^{-1}$, so this does not make any sense. Another error is when you say $g^{-1} \circ f^{-1} = (g \circ f)^{-1}$. This does not make sense, because $g^{-1} \circ f^{-1}$ is not defined (domain and codomain do not match). Moreover you have to prove that $f^{-1} \circ g^{-1} = (g \circ f)^{-1}$, not that $g^{-1} \circ f^{-1} = (g \circ f)^{-1}$.

Comment: Right, I'm sorry, it's was my mistake, I understand, is that today I'm a " little sleepy"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the correct proof.
$$(g \circ f) \circ (f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}) = (g \circ (f \circ f^{-1})) \circ g^{-1} = (g \circ id_B) \circ g^{-1} =g \circ g^{-1} =id_A$$
and
$$(f^{-1} \circ g^{-1}) \circ (g \circ f) = \mbox{ same computations } = id_C$$
so $(f^{-1} \circ g^{-1})$ and $(g \circ f)$ are inverses each other.